# redirect с POST данными

Tags: redirect, post

Всем привет.
Вопрос в следующем:
Есть данные, которые я обрабатываю на своем сервере, после чего из них необходимо сформировать POST запрос и сделать редирект пользователя на другой сервер отправив эти данные. т.е. как будто пользователь нажал кнопку submit формы, action которой на другом сервере. 
Как это можно сделать c помощью PHP?

Comment: Вся проблемма в том, что у меня и у сайта на который переходит пользователь после субмит формы, разные кодировки. Еслиб кодировки были одинаковы, пользователь бы нажал субмит и спокойно ушел на другой сайт.

Comment: Задачку решил скрытым фреймом. Единственной проблемой было разность кодировок моего сайта и внешнего ресурса. Сначала хотел обработать данные своим скриптом (перекодировать), а потом вместе с этими данными перенаправить пользователя на внешний ресурс. Но сделал по другому, создал файл с формой, открыл его в скрытом фрейме (в нужной мне кодировке), пользователю дал простую кнопку, по нажатию которой в форму фрейма записываются нужные данные и потом она субмитится. Всем спасибо )))

Answer (score 1):

может быть curl ?
отправляй пост запрос через библиотеку curl

Comment: Да запрос я отправлю, и ответ могу получить, только он мне не нужен, мне надо чтоб с данными POST на сторонний сайт отправился и пользователь тоже.

Answer (score 0):

Скрытый `<iframe>` содержащий само-submit-ющую форму ;-)

Answer (score -1):

аякс в помощь) Обрабатываете данные, формируете пост запрос и отправляете его на обработчик формы на другом сервере.

Comment: Вместе с данными мне еще надо пользователя перебросить на новую страницу

Answer (score -1):

Самый надежный способ сделать пустую страницу с формой с нужной информацией и на onload повесить сабмит формы. При этом форму можно делать и невидимую, для пользователя переход будет незаметным.

Comment: Вся соль в том, что кодировка моего сайта UTF8, а кодировка сайта для редиректа CP1251

Comment: Ну сделай эту страницу в 1251. Делов то.

Answer (score -2):

Страница редиректа:

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0; URL=http://simple.ru/index.php'>
</HEAD></HTML>
```

Непонятно, в чём проблема, может быть более конкретный пример приведёте, того, что вам сделать надо.